# sklearn wrapping an estimator causes error on get_params missing self

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to inherit from `BaseEstimator` and `MetaEstimatorMixin` to create a wrapping for a `base_estimator` but I am facing problems. I was trying to follow the `base_ensemble` code in the repository but it didn't help. I get `TypeError: get_params() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'` when running the test below which calls `check_estimator(Wrapper)`. According to documentation I don't have to implement get_params if I inherit from `BaseEstimator`. It seems like something is a class rather than an instance but I am not able to nail it down.

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin, RegressorMixin, MetaEstimatorMixin, clone
from functools import lru_cache
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

'''
this is a module containing classes which wraps a classifier or a regressor sklearn estimator
'''


class Wrapper(BaseEstimator, MetaEstimatorMixin):
    def __init__(self, base_estimator=LogisticRegression, estimator_params=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.base_estimator = base_estimator
        self.estimator_params = estimator_params

    def fit(self, x, y):
        self.model = self._make_estimator().fit(x,y)

    def _make_estimator(self):
        """Make and configure a copy of the `base_estimator_` attribute.
        Warning: This method should be used to properly instantiate new
        sub-estimators. taken from sklearn github
        """
        estimator = self.base_estimator()
        estimator.set_params(**dict((p, getattr(self, p))
                                    for p in self.estimator_params))

        return estimator

    def predict(self, x):
        self.model.predict(x)


import unittest
from sklearn.utils.estimator_checks import check_estimator
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_check_estimator(self):
        check_estimator(Wrapper)
```

Answer (score 3):

`base_estimator` field must be initialized with object, instead of Class.

```
....
def __init__(self, base_estimator=LogisticRegression(), ...
....
```

Your error happens because clone(safe=False) is used in some of tests.

> ```
> safe: boolean, optional
>     If safe is false, clone will fall back to a deepcopy on objects
>     that are not estimators.
> ```

Comment: Hi @Olologin, I have tried your change but it doesn't help as the check fails on other issue namely: "File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\estimator_checks.py", line 1419, in check_parameters_default_constructible
    np.float64, types.FunctionType, Memory])
AssertionError: <class 'sklearn.linear_model.logistic.LogisticRegression'> not found in [<class 'str'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'bool'>, <class 'tuple'>, <class 'NoneType'>, <class 'numpy.float64'>, <class 'function'>, <class 'sklearn.externals.joblib.memory.Memory'>]"

Comment: I have started an issue in the project's github:  [fail to write a wrapper class to an estimator #6079](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6079#issuecomment-166990309)